# How to display the name of symbols with glossaries-extra package?

Tags: symbols, glossaries, nomenclature, glossaries-extra

I am trying to produce a document that has a list of acronyms and a separate list of symbols.
My problem with the list of symbols is that I can't find how to add a name for the symbol itself.

I defined the symbol like that:

```
\glsxtrnewsymbol[
description={A cluster: a set of objects that are more similar to each other than to those in other clusters.}]
{cluster}
{\ensuremath{\vect{\mathcal{C}}}}
```

so I get this result:

[image]

But my desired result is something like that with three fields:
[image: Where $\mathcal{C}$ is aligned with the future symbols, \textbf{cluster} is aligned with future names, and all the future descriptions are also aligned]

Sorry if it is a trivial question and it is easily solvable [RTFM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM). I am new to glossaries and I find the documentation extremely confusing and I can't even find a reliable way to quickly get access to the complete list of arguments for most of the package commands. If you have a trick to quickly find all the options for any command of any package, please share that piece of information :)